# Java ProgressMonitorInputStream

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know how to use ProgressMonitorInputStream with DataInputStream?
I have to transfer file over socket, and I want the programm to show downloading progress using `readFully()` method of DataInputStream class.

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) is giving you trouble?

Comment: The part to showup the monitor progress. I have created a `ProgressMonitorInputStream` for a `socket.getInputStream()`, then I have wrapped it with `DataInputStream`. When I do `dataInputStream.readFully(new byte[dim])`, no monitor popup, neither invoking it in a `SwingWorker`